# Shortcut key to move the cursor from Expected to Actual in QC

Tags: manual-testing

What is the shortcut key to move the cursor from Expected to Actual during test execution in test lab?

Answer (score 2):

IF the cursor is in Expected, a simple tab will move th cursor to Actual

And shift-tab to move back to Expected